# Eisav Receiving Mechila/Kapara for Sins for a Halachikly Invalid Wedding?

Tags: forgiving-mechilah, esav, chassan-groom

[Megilla 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.17a.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says Nevaiot was הקדישהּ to Eisav.  The Talmud commentary called Siftei Chachamim, by [Rav Avraham Abbah Herzl](https://www.geni.com/people/Abraham-Herzl/6000000008906998) (20th century), suggests that Eisav’s wedding to Machalat wasn’t halachikly valid which implies that the קידושין wasn’t a true halachik one and in this context it has the meaning of designating. Nevaiot designated Machalat to Eisav.

> ומסתבר שקידשה ישמעאל לעשו, לאו קדושין כקדושי ישראל קאמר, כעין שנהגו האבות אלא כעין קידושי בן נח, כרמב"ם ריש הלכות אישות, וז"ל: קודם מתן תורה אדם פוגע אשה בשוק רצה הוא והיא לישא אותה מכניסה לתוך ביתו, ובועלה בינו לבין עצמו ותהיה לו לאשה (דלעכו"ם ביחוד בעלמא הוא אשתו), וכיון שבא עליה לשם אישות הוה לה אשת איש, שחבירו עכו"ם חייב עליה, כיון שנתנה תורה נצטוו ישראל, שאם ירצה האיש לישא אשה, יקנה אותה תחילה בפני עדים, ואח"כ תהיה לאשה שנאמר כי יקח איש אשה ובא עליה עיי"ש.

Given this, how can the [Yerushalmi Bikkurim 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.3.3.16?ven=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_translation_and_commentary_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=he) say Eisav received kapara for his sins if the wedding wasn’t halachikly valid?

Comment: Artscroll's comment doesn't seem right, because before the giving of the Torah marriage just meant cohabitation. See Maimonides in the beginning of Laws of Marriage.

Comment: @robev Someone from Artscroll informed me that the Siftei Chachamim referred to in that note is not the same Siftei Chachamim super-commentary on Rashi on Chumash.  The former is a commentary of various masechtot.  The author is Avraham Abba ben Yehoshua Hertzel.

Comment: Yes I figured. I'm impressed you have such a contact.

Comment: @N.T. see the quote from the sefer

Comment: Just to clarify your question, the Yerushalmi says a חתן is forgiven, and you're assuming Eisav didn't have the status of a חתן when he married her? Why not say that their "designation" is equivalent to our marriage? Although, I'll point out that חתן tends to focus on Nissuin, and our designation is Erusin.

Answer (score 1):

The Yerushalmi's entire source that a chassan's sins are forgiven is the verse by Eisav. So the how is that is how the Yerushalmi interprets what the Torah tells us about Eisav.

The next question is why would a non-halachic wedding work. The answer can be found in a parallel gemara in the [Bavli](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.3.3.16?ven=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_translation_and_commentary_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=he&p2=Chidushei_Rabbi_Eliyahu_of_Greiditz_on_Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.3.3.16.1&vhe2=Piotrk%C3%B3w,_1898-1900&lang2=he&p3=Sanhedrin.14a.10&ven3=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe3=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang3=he&p4=Chidushei_Agadot_on_Sanhedrin.14a.6&vhe4=Vilna_Edition&lang4=he) which says,

> אין אדם עולה לגדולה אלא א"כ מוחלין לו על כל עונותיו

The reason Chassan and the other cases in the Yerushalmi are forgiven is because of their promotion in life. This does not have to be halachic to be true.

Comment: I don't really see how you answered the question

Comment: I think it's pretty clear tbh. The point is non-halachic weddings also have forgiveness.

Comment: The question is how do non halachic weddings teach us regarding halachic weddings. You said it has to do with promotion. How do you know? Because the bavli says עולה לגדולה? Seems irrelevant. You instead should say the yerushalmi itself says גדולה, as well as נשיא, but it also lists חכם, so I'm not convinced.

Comment: @robev Kal Vachomer.

Comment: What's the Kal vachomer? Ein danin efshar meshiefshar ;-) in any event you didn't write that in your answer. as I said before, you didn't properly explain how you answered anything.

Comment: The questioner assumed ONLY halachic marriages would work, I showed why even non-halachic ones work. The tzad hashaveh of the cases of Yerushalmi are all an element of promotion, as said in the Bavli.  The Bavli and Yerushalmi are saying the same story with the same lesson, so definitely not irrelevant. If this doesn't satisfy you, nothing will. QED. Hatzlacha.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you see in the sifsei chachamim that the marraige wasn't valid. All he said that it wasn't kiddushin rather it was a ben noach marraige. That is a marraige,  to forbid her on other men. That is enough of a marraige (acc to Sifsei chachamim) to get your sins forgiven.

Comment: But how do you learn from there to our kiddushin/nisuin

Comment: @robev that's a good point. However maybe it's by nisuin that a person gets forgiven for your sins not kiddushin. Our nisuin is a closer connection than a ben noach marraige, so for sure you would be forgiven for your sins. (Acc to gur aryehs explanation of the matter of becoming new entity/ new person, that's why forgiven for sins...)